# msbuild - how to remove a string within a property

Tags: msbuild

If I have

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Prop1>C:\asdfsa\abc;C:\sadf\def;C:\asfddsa\abc;</Prop1>
</PropertyGroup>
```

How do I remove all entries that contain `\abc`?

I want final value of `$(Prop1)` to be `C:\sadf\def`.

Answer (score 1):

A property doesn't have 'entries', it's merely a string. You could fiddle with string splitting and/or regexes to erase some parts from it. On the other hand MSBuild also has Items which are more like proper lists. Going round via them is probably easier:

```
<Target Name="RemoveItemsFromProperty">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Prop1>C:\asdfsa\abc;C:\sadf\def;C:\asfddsa\abc;</Prop1>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Items Include="$(Prop1)"/>
    <FilteredItems Include="@(Items)" Condition="! $([System.String]::Copy('%(Identity)').Contains('\abc'))"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Prop1>@(FilteredItems)</Prop1>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="$(Prop1)" />
</Target>
```

**edit** ok the regex way is easier though I'm not 100% sure my pattern covers all cases:

```
<Target Name="RemoveItemsFromProperty">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Prop1>C:\asdfsa\abc;C:\sadf\def;C:\asfddsa\abc;</Prop1>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace('$(Prop1)', ';[.^;]\\abc', ''))" />
</Target>
```

Comment: FYI, MSBuild 14.0 and above allows this transform: `<FilteredItems Include="%(Items.Identity)" Condition="! @(Items->Contains('\abc')) " />`. This is batching per item, and expanding `@(Items)` to the current item only on every iteration, and here property functions are allowed. W/o batching, the condition will expand to something like `"! True;False;True"` tho, so the `%(Items.Identity)` is necessary. Oh, MSBuild is fun...